# Loop in nightwatchjs

Tags: loops, while-loop, nightwatch.js

I need some basic infinity loop, while is true to looping and clicking to elements.

```
'Infinity Loop' : function (browser) {
 browser
  .click('#refresh-button')
  .pause(2000)
  .click('#refresh-button')
  .pause(2000)
  .click('#refresh-button')
  .pause(2000)
  .click('#refresh-button')
  .pause(2000)
  .click('#refresh-button')
  .pause(2000)
```

This is just example what I need. Just to do same thing after some time. I'm trying to test some feed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [executeAsync](http://nightwatchjs.org/api/executeAsync.html) with setInterval. Documentation contains easy example.